# Java IO: file is not generated

Tags: java-io, filewriter

I've got Problems, when I try to generate a file in order to write into.
I don't get any exceptions and the sysouts are also displayed, but the File is not generated.. Is there something I don't see..?
this is the class, which does everything:

```
public class GraphMLWriter {

public FileWriter writer;
public File file;

private static GraphMLWriter instance;

private GraphMLWriter() {
    initFile();
}

public void initFile() {
    file = new File("myFile.txt");

    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
                    System.out.println("File erzeugt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void writeToFile() {
    try {
        writer.write("tolltoll");
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        writer.write("es klappt");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("File geschrieben");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static synchronized GraphMLWriter getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new GraphMLWriter();
    }
    return instance;
}
}
```

And it is called like this:

```
writer = GraphMLWriter.getInstance();
writer.writeToFile();
```

for the context: I've got a Spring 3 Application which connects to a Database and I want to write result sets into a generated xml-File! 
I just copied the code from another application where it worked properly

Comment: you mean something like file.createNewFile()...? I tried a view seconds ago, but it didn't work either... Is Spring special about that..?

Comment: it's strange, because I tested the code in a smaller context, before pasting it to the bigger on and there it worked fine!

Comment: You don't need to call `createNewFile`(). Clearly the file is being createed somewhere where you're not looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving full path like "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\myfile.txt" in the code

```
File file=new File("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\myfile.txt");
```